# How to calculate a field depending on previous records

Tags: ms-access

I want to create a calculated field (`Calc`) in Microsoft Access with a query that depends on previous records like this:

```
Debt    | Paid   | OrderDate | Calc
--------+--------+-----------+----------
$746.00 |  $0.00 | 20-Jul-17 |   $746.00
 $87.00 | $50.00 | 21-Jul-17 |   $783.00
$339.00 |  $0.00 | 23-Jul-17 | $1,122.00
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

You can use DSUM functions in your Calc column (where Table1 is your table name):

```
Calc: DSum("Debt","Table1","OrderDate <=#" & [OrderDate] & "#")-DSum("Paid","Table1","OrderDate <=#" & [OrderDate] & "#")
```

You may need additional conditions in the WHERE part of the DSum function, but the trick is using string concatenation to build up that condition.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works like charm. But don't you think because it is 3 query it will load slowly on large data?

Comment: Yes, it could be problematic on a larger dataset. This is the nature of calculating a running total dynamically. It depends on your business requirements, but I would try to limit how many rows I present where this calculation is called. You can put a calculation like this in a QueryDef, but then it has the potential process on all rows in the result set. I would try to put the calculation in a form control where the underlying result set is already limited.